# misleading usage of square bracket in SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml

I found the [] operator is sometimes confusing when it is used agains SimpleXMLElement object.

```
$level_a = $xml->children();
$level_a['name'];    # this returns the 'name' attribute of level_a (SimpleXmlElement object)
$level_a[0];         # this returns $level_a itself!
$level_a[1];         # this returns the second SimpleXmlElement object under root node. (Same level as level_a)
```

I can't find any documents about the numeric indexing usage of SimpleXmlElement class. Can anybody explain how those two worked?

Note that it seems this [num] operator of SimpleXmlElement just mimic the behavior of Array. I feel that this is not something stirred with Array, but the implementation of SimpleXmlElement class.

Comment: By the way, the term is "index," not "subscribe."  The 0th index, the 1st index, the 'name' index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe anything magical is going on here. An array in PHP can keyed by an integer, and may be keyed by a string as well. So the `$xml->children()` line is likely making an array of key-value attribute pairs in the form

```
foreach (attrs($element) as $attribute_name => $attribute_value)
    $array[$attribute_name] = $attribute_value;
$array[0] = $element;
// etc.
```

Comment: I don't think that I can always index PHP array by integer. Consider this: 

$myarray = array(
    'a' => 'Apple', 
    'b' => 'Banana', 
    'c' => 'Cherry'
);
print_r($myarray);

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    print $myarray[$i] . "\n";
}

Subscribing by number doesn't work in this case.

Comment: But: `$myarray = array( 'a' => 'Apple', 0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar' );`   Keys are keys are keys, no matter if they're integers or strings.

Comment: OK, I understand what you said. But according to the specification of SimpleXmlElement, the children() function simply return yet another SimpleXmlElement object, not an array.

Comment: The documentation refers to it as a "psuedo-array" and says it "follows normal iteration rules." See http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

Comment: Thank you :) So, yes, there is some magic there. I need a specific description of the [] operator of SimpleXMLElement. I want to know how it works.

Comment: @solotim read through the "basic usage" manual page: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic